# Remove the end closing P element after inline element like SPAN and STRONG in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

This is very weird. I am getting end closing `</p>` tag after HTML element like `<span>` or `<strong>`. No opening tag.

Below is sample HTML code I write in classic editor

```html
<div class="blck>
  <div class="col-1">
    <strong>Heading 1</strong>
    <ul>
      <li>list......</li>
      <li>list......</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <strong>Heading 2</strong>
    <ul>
      <li>list......</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the output i get

```html
<div class="blck>
  <div class="col-1">
    <strong>Heading 1</strong></p>
    <ul>
      <li>list......</li>
      <li>list......</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <strong>Heading 2</strong></p>
    <ul>
      <li>list......</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note the `</p>` after `</strong>`**

Same thing is happening for `<span>` element.

One solution is that I remove the WordPress filter `wpautop`. But then I have to manually add `p` tags for paragraphs. Which is very cumbersome problem because we I have lots of content to edit.

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new line in between those html element

For example

```
<div class="col-1">

  <strong>Heading 1</strong>

  <ul>
    <li>List here</li>
    <li>List here</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Then this enclose `<strong>Heading 1</strong>` inside `<p>` tag. Which is not the required output